# pgfplot: plot non-numerical data from CSV file

Tags: pgfplots, plot

I have a csv file like:

```
column1,column2
string1,value1
string2,value2
…
```

Values are integers, strings are alphanumeric.

I tried to plot it, with strings on x axis and values on y axis. After some tries leading to errors like `Could not parse input "string1" as a floating point number, sorry. The unreadable part was near…`, based on some questions (like [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163590/pgfplots-not-plotting-bar-graph-with-all-symbolic-coordinates?rq=1), [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11159/maths-expression-in-coordinates-for-a-bar-chart), [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/207807/is-it-possible-to-plot-non-numerical-data-alongside-normal-data-in-a-normal-plot), [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/160869/missing-tick-labels-for-symbolic-coords-in-second-plot) or [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153853/pgfplots-how-to-load-distinct-symbolic-ticks-labels-from-file)), i finally found this only way to get the things works, (see also [the doc](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/pgfplots.pdf), page 363):

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    symbolic x coords={string1,string2,string3,…},
    minor tick num=1,
]
\addplot table [x=column1,y=column2] {csvfile.csv}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Obviously, the non-numerical data needs to be write directly in the graph definition.

How can i have the same in a DRY way, i.e. have for only source of data the CSV file given as `\addplot` parameter ?

Comment: See if [Using Labels from a File in PGFplot](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/21224) helps

Comment: I didn't found this one in my search, but give me the answer. Thanks for pointing it. My question seems to be a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to torbjørn-t comment, i finally found [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21220/using-labels-from-a-file-in-pgfplot/21224#21224) and the `xticklabels from table={<table or file name>}{<column name>}` option.

Here is the final working code:

```
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{path/to/csv}\datatable
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        ybar,
        xtick=data,
        xticklabels from table={\datatable}{column1},
    ]
    \addplot table [col sep=comma, x expr=\coordindex, y=column2] {path/to/csv};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```