# Plotting non nummerical data from csv file using pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, csv

so I'm trying to plot a csv file using pgfplots. The csv file looks like this but with more data:

[image: csv file]

Here is the download link for the csv: https://datawrapper.dwcdn.net/NDCZf/4/

I tried using the code from this post [pgfplot: plot non-numerical data from CSV file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/311781/pgfplot-plot-non-numerical-data-from-csv-file) . But I end up with something like this:

[image: result]

Here is the code:

```tex
\documentclass[ngerman]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\input{../shared/twp-cfg}


\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{../shared/data.csv}\datatable
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        ybar,
        xtick=data,
        xticklabels from table={\datatable}{X},
        xticklabel style={rotate=90,anchor=base,yshift=0.82cm},
    ]
    \addplot table [col sep=comma, x expr=\coordindex, y=Terawatt-Hours(TWh)] {../shared/data.csv};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Is there a way to fix this and make the plot wider?
I'm new to LaTeX, so any help would be welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Pleas add to your question `data.csv` and minimum code from `\documentclass{...` to `\end{document}`

Comment: Very good! Thank you! Still missing `data.csv` (the link only shows a graph) and `twp-cfg`

Answer (score 1):

This example will help you get started.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
 
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usepackage{pgfplots}
 \pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.9}
 \usetikzlibrary{dateplot}
 
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{TRW.dat}
        date,  TRW
    2010-11-01, 0.2
    2010-12-01, 1
    2011-01-01, 2
    2011-02-01, 5
    2011-03-01, 9
    2011-04-01, 15
    2011-05-01, 9
    2011-06-01, 10
    2011-07-01, 10.5
    2011-08-01, 14
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        date coordinates in=x,
        ybar,
        xtick=data,
        xticklabel style= {rotate=90,anchor=near xticklabel},
        xticklabel=\month --\year,
        title={Energy Consumption},
        xlabel={Date},
        ylabel={Monthly, in terawatt-hours (TWh)},
        ]
        \addplot table[col sep=comma,x=date,y=TRW] {TRW.dat};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```